# Why is useFetch returning HTML instead of a JSON object following a request to api?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nitro

I am making a request to an API route, and the useFetch() method is returning HTML instead of JSON. I have attempted to comment out code blocks and manually test everything step-by-step to no avail. Is there something I am doing wrong? The API route is within server/api/auth.ts

```js
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/auth/exists/email', {
    query: {
        email_address: enteredEmail.value
    }, 
    baseURL: '/api/auth/exists/email',
    onResponseError: ({error}) => {
        console.error(error);
        registrationErrors.email.push('An unexpected error has occurred.')
    }
});
```

And in return, I am receiving this:

```html
RESPONSE:  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/@vueform/multiselect/themes/default.css"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/@vueform/toggle/themes/default.css"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/.cache/nuxt-google-fonts/css/nuxt-google-fonts.css"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/vite-plugin-vue-inspector/src/Overlay.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=31d1379f&lang.css"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/AppHeader.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/AuthModal.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=ff55f906&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/Modal.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=0b5a066a&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/FormGroup.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=6b1d710f&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/ErrorBox.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=c34b980e&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/TextInput.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=4f98be6b&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/Checkbox.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=84f5ff5b&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/ButtonPrimary.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=fcc59362&lang.scss"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_nuxt/components/AppHeaderSubMenu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.scss"><link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/Users/hayden/Desktop/k_discuss/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.js"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/@vueform/multiselect/themes/default.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/@vueform/toggle/themes/default.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/.cache/nuxt-google-fonts/css/nuxt-google-fonts.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/node_modules/vite-plugin-vue-inspector/src/Overlay.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=31d1379f&lang.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/AppHeader.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/AuthModal.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=ff55f906&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/Modal.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=0b5a066a&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/FormGroup.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=6b1d710f&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/ErrorBox.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=c34b980e&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/TextInput.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=4f98be6b&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/Checkbox.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=84f5ff5b&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/ButtonPrimary.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=fcc59362&lang.scss"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/components/AppHeaderSubMenu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.scss"><script>
window.__NUXT_DEVTOOLS_TIME_METRIC__ = window.__NUXT_DEVTOOLS_TIME_METRIC__ || {}
window.__NUXT_DEVTOOLS_TIME_METRIC__.appInit = Date.now()
</script></head>
<body ><div id="__nuxt"><div data-v-inspector="app.vue:2:3"><div data-v-inspector="layouts/default.vue:2:5"><div data-v-inspector="components/AppHeader.vue:2:5"><header class="app-header" data-v-inspector="components/AppHeader.vue:3:9"><img src="/_nuxt/assets/img/kd_logo.png" alt="Knox Discuss Logo" class="logo" data-v-inspector="components/AppHeader.vue:4:13"><button class="login-btn" data-v-inspector="components/AppHeader.vue:5:13"><span></span><span data-v-inspector="components/AppHeader.vue:7:17">Login / Register</span></button></header><!----></div><div class="menu-bar" data-v-inspector="components/AppHeaderSubMenu.vue:2:5"><a class="menu-bar__link" href="#" data-v-inspector="components/AppHeaderSubMenu.vue:3:9"><span></span> Live Feed </a><a class="menu-bar__link" href="#" data-v-inspector="components/AppHeaderSubMenu.vue:9:9"><span></span> Channels </a><a class="menu-bar__link" href="#" data-v-inspector="components/AppHeaderSubMenu.vue:15:9"><span></span> Trending </a></div><!--[--> hi <!--]--></div></div></div><script type="application/json" id="__NUXT_DATA__" data-ssr="true">[["Reactive",1],{"data":2,"state":3,"_errors":6,"serverRendered":7,"path":8,"pinia":9},{},{"$s__nuxt_devtools__":4},{"timeSsrStart":5},1689438997965,{},true,"/api/auth/exists/email",{"modal":10},{"authModalIsOpen":11},["EmptyRef",12],"false"]</script><script>window.__NUXT__={};window.__NUXT__.config={public:{},app:{baseURL:"/",buildAssetsDir:"/_nuxt/",cdnURL:""}}</script><script type="module" src="/_nuxt/@vite/client" crossorigin></script><script type="module" src="/_nuxt/Users/hayden/Desktop/k_discuss/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.js" crossorigin></script></body>
</html>
```

Here is my API route:

```js
router.get('/exists/email', defineEventHandler(event => {

    try{

        const queryParams = getQuery(event);

      /*
        if(!queryParams['email_address']){
            throw new ResponseError({
                status_code: 422, 
                short_msg: 'ERR_MISSING_INFO', 
                body: {
                    message: 'Missing email.'
                }
            });
        }

        const { data } = await $fetch(`${accountAPIUri}/auth/exists/username`, {
            query: {
                email_address: queryParams['email_address']
            }, 
            onResponseError({error}) {
                console.error(error);
            },
        });

        console.log(data.value);
        
        */

        return {
            data: 1234
        };

    }catch(e) {

        return ResponseError.respondWithError(e);

    }

}))

export default useBase('/api/auth', router.handler);
```

Comment: were you able to solve this? Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It is likely an issue with the value given to `baseUrl` option.
You should check request URL is correct.

In my case, I want to request to `http://example.com/api/test` and I wrote code like this:

```
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/test', {
    method: 'GET',
    baseURL: 'example.com'
});
```

and I faced the same issue.
The HTML string in `data`.

I checked the Network panel in the Chrome DevTools.
The `useFetch` was accessing a page on my own dev server `http://localhost:13100/example.com/api/test`.

[DevTools view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxC7m.png)

So, I added URL scheme in `baseUrl` and I solved it.

```
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/test', {
    method: 'GET',
    baseURL: 'http://example.com'
});
```

I think the HTML string is body of 404 page at `http://localhost:13100/example.com/api/test`.